# is it possible to deploy cloud foundry into multi physical node directly?

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry

I'm a fresher for Cloud Foundry. And I have setup a local environment following [Deploying Cloud Foundry](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/deploying/). Then I want to deploy the components of Cloud Foundry into different physical node directly, because i have no AWS or Openstack environment.

So, my question is: 
Is it possible to deploy cloud foundry into multi physical node directly?  and how?
Should I study BOSH, if not, what  should do?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to deploy Cloud Foundry into a physical node directly, in it's current form Cloud Foundry needs to have a Infrastructure as a Service (IAAS) to manage the virtual machines that hold the different components.

If you want to work with Cloud Foundry understanding BOSH is essential.  A good place to start is to see how others have implemented BOSH releases.  A favorite of mine is the RabbitMQ BOSH release [here](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/cf-rabbitmq-release).

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Foundry PaaS is deployed using [BOSH](https://bosh.io/docs/).

> BOSH is a project that unifies release engineering, deployment, and lifecycle management of small and large-scale cloud software. BOSH can provision and deploy software over hundreds of VMs. It also performs monitoring, failure recovery, and software updates with zero-to-minimal downtime.

You can deploy CF as long as you can implement [Bosh CPI](https://bosh.io/docs/build-cpi/) that is dedicated for your "multi physical node" infrastructure.

For example, you can provide [these REST endpoints](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/bosh-openstack-cpi-release/blob/master/docs/openstack-api-calls.md) and use [OpenStack CPI](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/bosh-openstack-cpi-release) :)